# MYSQL Query Matching Count

Tags: mysql, subquery

I have a MySQL-question which I can't seem to figure out.

I have two query's and some PHP and I think it should be possible to merge this into one query.

The thing I want to do is: show all users that completed **all** modules of a certain programm with id=1

Query 1 -> this gives all modules of the programm:

```
SELECT `id` 
FROM `modules` 
JOIN `linkModuleProgramm` ON `module`.`id` = `linkModuleProgramm`.`module` 
WHERE `linkModuleProgramm`.`programm` = 1
```

Query 2 -> this gives the user and the number of modules of the programm that are completed by this user:

```
SELECT `user`.`id`, 
COUNT(*) as 'count' 
FROM `user` 
JOIN `linkUserModule` ON `user`.`id` = `linkUserModule`.`user` 
WHERE `linkUserModule`.`status` = 1 
AND `linkUserModule`.`module` IN (Query1) 
GROUP BY `user`.`id`
```

Then PHP filters the users from Query2 where 'count' is equal to the number of results from Query1.

Anyone has a suggestion?

Comment: Are you trying to say that currently you do Query 1, then you do a query that is like Query 2 but with the text of Query 1 substitued for "Query1" and then you filter in PHP, but that you would like it all in one query? Please make this clear.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I haven't understood your question right the first time. Another try, using two queries and MySQL variable:

```
SET @MODULESCOUNT = (
   SELECT COUNT(*) 
   FROM `modules` 
   JOIN `linkModuleProgramm` ON `module`.`id` = `linkModuleProgramm`.`module` 
   WHERE `linkModuleProgramm`.`programm` = 1 
   );
SELECT `user`.`id`, 
 FROM `user` 
  JOIN `linkUserModule` ON `user`.`id` = `linkUserModule`.`user` 
 WHERE `linkUserModule`.`status` = 1 
  AND `linkUserModule`.`module` IN (Query1) 
 GROUP BY `user`.`id`
  HAVING COUNT(*)=@MODULESCOUNT ;
```

There is also a possibility to use 'subquery' instead of variable:

```
SELECT `user`.`id`, 
 FROM `user` 
  JOIN `linkUserModule` ON `user`.`id` = `linkUserModule`.`user` 
 WHERE `linkUserModule`.`status` = 1 
  AND `linkUserModule`.`module` IN (Query1) 
 GROUP BY `user`.`id`
  HAVING COUNT(*)=
  (
   SELECT COUNT(*) 
   FROM `modules` 
   JOIN `linkModuleProgramm` ON `module`.`id` = `linkModuleProgramm`.`module` 
   WHERE `linkModuleProgramm`.`programm` = 1 
  )
```

but I don't like subqueries inside 'where' or 'having' sections, mysql sometimes decides to do unreasonably inefficient things because of them.